# Lucene: Indexing a stream (not available in a buffer)

Tags: stream, lucene, buffer

I'd like to use Lucene to index a stream as it is being read.  Due to the size of the data and limited RAM, I can't put the whole thing into a buffer; instead, I want Lucene to consume from the stream, index, wait for more data to be available, consume more, until EOF.

Lucene should only buffer what it needs to: that is, partial tokens until enough chars have been acquired to end the token.

Can I do that with Lucene? How?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass a `Reader` into your field constructor, rather than a `String`.  I believe this would not need to read the entire field into memory (I haven't really done a great of testing on this).  You would not be able to make the field *stored*, but if you can't load it into memory anyway, why would you want to?

However, I don't believe there is any way to read only partial *tokens* at a time.  I believe you would need to be able to load each token into memory at an absolute minimum.  If your tokens are so large as to overflow available memory, you probably need to rethink your analysis scheme.